# Function produces null string instead of output (C)

Tags: c, string, pointers, null

I am writing a program that can convert a base 10 number to a different base between 2 and 16. I have written my function like this, and I think it is correct:

```html
char* baseConversion(int number, int base, char *word)
{
       
       if (number != 0) {
  
       int x = number % base;
       
       if( x > 9){
           
           if(x == 10)
           *word = 'A';
           
           if(x == 11)
           *word = 'B';
           
           if(x == 12)
           *word = 'C';
           
           if(x == 13)
           *word = 'D';
           
           if(x == 14)
           *word = 'E';
           
           if(x == 15)
           *word = 'F';
           
           baseConversion(number/base, base, word+1);
           
           }
           
       else {
            *word = x;
            baseConversion(number/base, base, word+1);
            }
        
        
       
       
       }
       
}
```

I have my main function set up to test it:

```html
int main(){
        int num, base;
        
        char word[20];
        
        scanf("%d %d", &num, &base);
        
        baseConversion(num, base, word);

        printf("%s", word);
        
        system("PAUSE");
        
        
        
        }
```

When I feed it input (my test case was 15 16, which should evaluate to F) I instead get the word null. I am not passing my string correctly? Or is my pointer arithmetic off?

Note: Also I am aware this will give me a reversed answer, I can use fix that later when I am not getting a null answer.

Comment: there is no 'return' statement in your function which is supposed to return as per function definition

Comment: @KevalDoshi: That's OK, since OP ignores what would get returned, anyway :)

Comment: But shouldn't the pointer allow it to be modified outside of a return statement?

Comment: Not the issue: you declared the function to return a string, you don't, but your call to it doesn't use it anyway.

Comment: put `*(word+1)='\0';` at the end of your `baseConversion(..)`

Comment: I added in the terminating symbol '/0', and that makes all of the atomic characters (1-15) function correctly. However, I am still getting garbage when I put in a number bigger than that.

Comment: @user4159242 it's because you didn't do any thing for the digit `1-9`.

Comment: The else case of *word = x should cover that, shouldn't it?

Comment: I got it working. I had to hardcode in the other 9 numbers but it works now. Thank you for all the advice everyone. :>

Answer (score 0):

For `num<10`, you aren't inserting the character for that digit (for example, you should put in a `'0'` when `x==0`).  To verify: try a value which is all letters in base 16.  (Of course, you never terminate the string, either, so you'll probably see some funky stuff...)

(Also, your code won't work for bases other than 16, since you have 16 hard-coded in there.)